# Doctrine not loading entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get object `pageContent` from my `page` entity.

The mapping is set up such:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="integer", name="pageContentId")
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="PageContent")
 * @JoinColumn(name="pageContentId", referencedColumnName="pageContentId")
 * @var PageContent
 */
protected $pageContent;
```

However, when I try to do `$page->getPageContent()` it returns the ID as an integer and not the page content object. No errors or warnings thrown.

Why am I not getting the target entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the @Column part. That line says this property should be the pageContentId column, not an Entity.